# Regex in perl prints just first instance

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to read from file, line by line, and if a line contains something from regex, print that line.

```
my $file = 'test.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    if ($line =~ /\d\d\W\d\d\W\d\d/) {
        print $&;
    }
}
```

Test file

```
        <td align='center'>0</td></tr><tr><td style='width:1px;padding:0px;'><img src='styles/images/cat/bluray.png' alt='Blu-ray'></td>
        <td><a href='details.php?id=313788&hit=1'><b>The.Raid.2.2014.1080p.BluRay.REMUX.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.5.1.RoSubbed...</b></a></td>
        <td align='center' style='width:1px;'><font class='small'>2014-06-27<br />03:39:15</font></td>
        <td align='center'>0</td>
        <td align='center'>0</td></tr><tr><td style='width:1px;padding:0px;'><img src='styles/images/cat/bluray.png' alt='Blu-ray'></td>
        <td><a href='details.php?id=313781&hit=1'><b>Rio.2.2014.Blu-ray.REMUX.1080p.AVC.DTS-HD.MA.7.1.RoSubbed-playBD</b></a></td>
        <td align='center' style='width:1px;'><font class='small'>2014-06-27<br />00:27:25</font></td>
        <td align='center'>48</td>
        <td align='center'>33</td></tr><tr><td style='width:1px;padding:0px;'><img src='styles/images/cat/hdtv.png' alt='HDTV'></td>
        <td><a href='details.php?id=313717&hit=1'><b>Cosmos. A Spacetime Odyssey 2014 1080p BluRay DD5.1 x264-DON</b></a></td>
        <td align='center' style='width:1px;'><font class='small'>2014-06-26<br />16:26:30</font></td>
        <td align='center'>19</td>
```

Right now it prints just the first instance that finds, and there are more in the file. If I want to print $line in place of $&, it prints every line of the file like the IF statement is true every time.

Comment: Can you show sample input data?

Comment: What's in the test file please?

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't in DOS format line endings (and thus being read as a single line)? Add `print "COUNT=" . $count++ . "\n";` inside the loop to test

Comment: @DVK I think it's the other way around. A Unix file will seem like one line on Windows. A Windows file will be multiple lines on Unix, but it will have an extra `CR` character at the end of each line.

Comment: @Barmar - yep. \r missing

Comment: Thank you DVK, this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you get `count=0` as per your comment, it means you are actually processing ONE single line - your file gets slurped in 100%.

This usually happens when you have a mismatch between input record separator `$/` and the file's line ending character, due to one being Windows and one being Unix: Unix newlines are `"\n"` character whereas DOS/Windows are `"\r\n"`

To fix, the following approaches would work:

1. Convert the file from Unix to Windows format (on Unix side, use `unix2dos` command)
2. Change `$/` to `"\n"`.
3. Slurp the file entirely (using `my $data = File::Slurp::read_file($filename);`) and then split $data on `"\n"` character into lines.

Comment: `<>` stops reading when it sees a LF (the value of `$/`), which both unix and Windows files have. The problem would only happen if you have ancient MacOS files (terminated by CR). @Barmar, this comment is for you too.

Comment: None of your solutions will help. `$/` is already `"\n"` on both Windows and unix. `unix2dos` won't help. And he's already doing the equivalent of the last one.

Comment: @ikegami - "Thank you DVK, this was the problem!" - from OP's comments. :)

Comment: Your answer is still completely wrong. (The file isn't being slurped, and those fixes won't stop a file from being slurped.) It just means the OP's description is also completely wrong too.

Comment: If it helped, then he's on unix with a Windows file, he was doing `while (<>) { print $& if /.*/; }`, he was seeing the last match (not the first), all the matches are printed out, and the problem is that the lines are being printed over each other.

Comment: @ikegami - the count being 0 and not rising indicates slurping.

Comment: Going in circles here. Your answer is still completely wrong. (If your solution helped, the file isn't being slurped, as those fixes won't stop a file from being slurped.) It just means the OP's description is also completely wrong too.